# Express & handlebars is defanging my html (turning into entities)

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using Express with Handlebars to serve a string that I have manually wrapped with anchor tags:

```
/* stub function */
function generateLinks(text) {

        const reg = /\b__([\w\/]+)__\b/g;
        const tags = text.replace(reg, "<a href=$1>$1</a>");
        return tags;
}

[...]

const fanged = generateLinks('__foo__');
res.render('template', { 'fanged' : fanged });

[...]
```

But after the data is passed to express's `render` call, i.e, in the browser, the angle brackets have been defanged, either by express or handlebars:

```
&lt;a href&#x3D;/foo&gt;/foo&lt;/a&gt;
```

How do I hunt down where this is happening? Is there a setting to turn this off?

---

Edit for Kemal:

```
<div>
{{fanged}}
</div>
```

---

Edit for 76484:
That was helpful! For posterity, it is handlebars defanging the input. The solution is to use triple mustaches around the particular token you want passed verbatim:

```
{{{fanged}}}
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the template file?

Comment: Perhaps this will be of help: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, it is the handlebars library that was defanging the input. The solution is to use **triple mustaches** around the particular token you want passed in verbatim via `render`:

```
{{{fanged}}}
```

That's all.